Print path to a node using Google Guava Graph library
Is there a way to save/print path to a node using the guava graph library?
I looked into SuccessorsFunction and Traverser but cant seem to find an example.

What do you mean by "a path to a node"?  (Usually 'path' implies a starting point as well as an ending point.)  Do you already have a path (if so, how represented?) or are you looking for something to calculate the path for you?
